# To prepare for something or to get prepared for something?

Tags: verbs, american-english, collocations

Which one is correct in American English?

> 1) To **prepare** for something?
>
> 2) To **get prepared** for something?

Besides this, there are a lot of similar things that I am not sure about (such as to start or to get started). How can I generally realize which form is correct?

Comment: Both can be OK but it depends on context. In order not to make guesses, you should add some example sentences using the phrases in question.

Answer (score 1):

Both (1) and (2) are correct and commonly used forms and they mean almost exactly the same thing. The very subtle difference is that "to prepare" implies that the subject is actively to do the preparing while "to get prepared" *could* mean that the preparation is to be done for them.

Answer (score 1):

**Prepare** is a verb.  To prepare for something is to engage in the action of preparing.

**Prepared** is an adjective.  It refers to being in a state of having completed preparations.

**To prepare** and **to get prepared** both refer to the same process, but with a slightly different nuance.  **To prepare** focuses on the process of preparing, with no explicit attention to how long that will take.  "We're preparing to send astronauts to Mars" is a true statement even if it is a minimal or sporadic effort occurring over decades.

**To get prepared** focuses on the end result.  For preparation of a short duration, either phrase might be used.  But it wouldn't be typical to select "to get prepared" when referring to a very long process that involved a lot of "biding time", or preliminary work to facilitate the task, like preparing to send astronauts to Mars.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is wrong but in most cases *To (verb)* is preferable to *To get (verbed)*.

Sometimes that means we need *to prepare my/one/yourself* and that’s a different question.

Answer (score 0):

We should get going = we ought to be leaving

We should go = we ought to leave

The difference is that with **get**, the action is understood to be underway, to have commenced. That is, the *action to be 'gotten'* is one that is already underway.

Comment: I have to disagree here. The sense of action underway is carried by the use of the imperfect verb "go*ing*". "We should get going." can be understood as "We should obtain the character of one who is going." It means that the action should happen now and not that the action should have already started.

Comment: If my Pa said "Get prepared for a whoopin'", I guarantee it isn't happening yet.

Comment: What I meant is that with **get**, the action to be 'gotten' is an action already underway.

Comment: The action is one that should already be happening now.  Not that it was happening in the *past* but that it should be *underway* now. We must be acting.  We should be actors engaged in an action that is beyond incipient.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are **correct**.

- When you say '**to get**', it is implied that you will get started (or do the verb) either **straight away or soon**.
- If you decide to just leave it and say '**to**', you declare that it is something that needs to happen, but **not straight away**.

If you were to ask a friend that you need to study for an exam coming up in a week, you would say...

> "... and I need **to get started** on studying for English for the test **this week**."

Compare this to the alternative, this sounds much more **realistic**. This is how you'd distinct which one to use. To '**get**' something done is implied that you want it done soon.

Answer (score 0):

To prepare for the exam, Cuthbert spent many hours in quiet study.

To get prepared for the exam, Cathy drank a cup of cocoa and put on her extra strong reading glasses.

‘Prepare’ is more passive.

‘Get prepared’ (or get anything) focuses more on the action involved, and on the process, because ‘get’ describes the process of transitioning from not having - to having something.

Here’s another example:

He was drunk - describes his state. Nothing is happening - we just passively hear a description of how he now ‘is’. ie ‘drunk’. He is probably asleep on the staircase, key in hand.

He got drunk - is a whole other story - in fact it IS a story - it alludes to the *process* of how he got drunk. We might hear of several bars visited, various cocktails imbibed and bartenders met, in that ‘story’ of how he ‘got drunk’.

So neither is wrong - and the one you choose depends on whether you want to ‘describe the current status’ or ‘allude to the process’.

With start, or get started, the ‘get’ provides the impetus for the starting to happen - like a spark that ignites - again, it alludes to the process.

- ‘He started the course’ - passive
- ‘He needed the teachers encouragement to get started’ - impetus to the process starting is provided by the teacher.
- ‘The bike started’
- ‘He kicked down the bike to get it started’
- ‘At last the bike got started - sputtering into life’.